# dimple js x-axis date issue with bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

My bar chart bars on x-axis is adding to the right positions but the x-axis ticks are duplicating month and year in the dimple js. How can I adjust the x-axis as I have only three values in this data? Here is the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/17/

Any suggestions?

```
var dim = {"width":590,"height":450}; //chart container width
var data = [{"date":"01-02-2010","cost":"11.415679194952766"},{"date":"01-03-2010","cost":"10.81875691467018"},{"date":"01-04-2010","cost":"12.710197879070897"}];


function barplot(id,dim,data)
{
    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var xcord = keys[0];
    var ycord = keys[1];
    var svg = dimple.newSvg(id, dim.width, dim.height);

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);        

    //var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", xcord);
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", xcord, "%d-%m-%Y","%b %Y");
    x.addOrderRule(xcord);
    x.showGridlines = true;

    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", ycord);
    y.showGridlines = true;
    y.tickFormat = ',.1f';    

    var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    var s1 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    s1.lineWeight = 3;
    s1.lineMarkers = true;

    myChart.draw(1500);

}

barplot("body",dim,data);
```

Comment: How are they in the wrong position?

Comment: Let me edit the post. I mean x-axis order is getting messed up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent the excess ticks/labels by setting the time period for the axis to months:

```
x.timePeriod = d3.time.months;
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/19/).

Comment: Thanks for that. Now the bars are so apart and size of the bars needs to change as well. Any fix of that?

Comment: To pre-empt your next question, here's how you can automatically set the max and min bounds to account for the bar width: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/26/

Comment: This works with only 3 data values. However, in my case data is updating dynamically and more data mess up the chart, here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/31/

Comment: You can set it dynamically depending on the amount of data: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra2xS/32/